# Analog clock with UIImages for hands?

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

I want to know how to make an analog clock in iPhone SDK. However, I want the hands of the clock to be custom images and not squares drawn over like in this tutorial:  http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2010/03/analog-clock-using-quartz-core.html

The problem with that tutorial is that the clock hands are drawn with Quarzt Core.  I'm okay with that as long as the hands could be custom.  What would be the easiest way to make an Analog Clock this way?

Comment: The answer here is pretty on target as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499996/any-example-iphone-code-for-an-analog-clock (don't need CALayers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do it with CALayers. is WAY much easier and performance is better this way.

```
CALayer *handLayer = [CALayer layer];
handLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"hand.png"].CGImage;
handLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.0)];
[myview.layer addSublayer:handLayer];

//i.e.: if handLayer represents the seconds hand then repeat this every second ;)
handLayer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle); //set the angle here
```

**UPDATE:**

I wrote a [ClockView sample using CALayers](https://github.com/nacho4d/ClockView), maybe you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll go look through the CALayers/Core Animation Programming Guide.

Comment: It says that .contents and .anchorPoint are not not in structure or onion.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add QuartzCore.Framework to your project and #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> to your file ;)

Answer (score 0):

this one uses raphael js
http://jsfiddle.net/8srjq/

> ```
>             function start(){
>                 canvas = Raphael("clock",200, 200);
>                 var h_sign;
>                 for(i=0;i<24;i++){
>                     var p = Math.round(40*Math.cos(15*i*Math.PI/180));
>                     if(p==40 || p==-40 || p==0){
>                         var start_x = 100+Math.round(35*Math.cos(15*i*Math.PI/180));
>                         var start_y = 100+Math.round(35*Math.sin(15*i*Math.PI/180));                        
>
>                     }else{
>                         var start_x = 100+Math.round(39*Math.cos(15*i*Math.PI/180));
>                         var start_y = 100+Math.round(39*Math.sin(15*i*Math.PI/180));  
>                     }
>
>                     var end_x = 100+Math.round(47*Math.cos(15*i*Math.PI/180));
>                     var end_y = 100+Math.round(47*Math.sin(15*i*Math.PI/180));    
>                     h_sign = canvas.path("M"+start_x+" "+start_y+"L"+end_x+" "+end_y);
>                     h_sign.attr({stroke:"#888","stroke-width":1})
>                 }    
>                 h_hand = canvas.path("M100 100L100 70");
>                 h_hand.attr({stroke: "#eee", "stroke-width": 3});
>                 min_hand = canvas.path("M100 100L100 65");
>                 min_hand.attr({stroke: "#eee", "stroke-width": 2});
>                 sec_hand = canvas.path("M100 110L100 55");
>                 sec_hand.attr({stroke: "#f00", "stroke-width": 1}); 
>                 var pin = canvas.circle(100, 100, 2);
>                 pin.attr("fill", "#fff");    
>                 setInterval(function(){
>                    var now = new Date();
>                    var h = now.getHours();
>                    var min = now.getMinutes();
>                    var sec = now.getSeconds();
>                    h_hand.rotate(30*h+(min/2.5), 100, 100);
>                    min_hand.rotate(6*min, 100, 100);
>                    sec_hand.rotate(6*sec, 100, 100);
>                 },1000);
>             }​ </script>
> ```

hope useful