# -[UIView layoutSubviews]; called every time in animation?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I just wrote an answer for someone else and when testing It turns out that `layoutSubViews` method is called every time I animate some layers (every time the timer fires). I am not modifying the frame of the UIView. layoutSubviews shouldn't be called only once in this case?

I would appreciate if someone could explain why is this happening

My answer is here:
[Object angle based on current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843563/object-angle-based-on-current-time/4844126#4844126)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure I agree with your linked answer: I don't see how layers are a better approach than views, given how UIViews are basically just wrappers around a CALayer designed to make life easier.

In the absence of anyone else, I *think* what's happening is because you've added your clock layers as sublayers of a single UIView when you transform those layers it *appears* to UIKit that you've changed the geometry of your main view, causing layoutSubviews to be called. But that's an educated guess more than anything. Perhaps somebody will come along with a better idea.

Comment: I said that in this case Layers are better since with layers there is no necessity of redrawing the complete view. (Implementing drawRect: method with CoreGraphics calls) Layers are light weight and probably in this example there is no such a difference but in a more complicated case there should be. I will try to add a container layer so see if your guess is correct ;)