# Moving UIImage clock hands?

Tags: ios, rotation, uiimage, geometry, clock

I am working on creating an analog clock in X-code and am having issues figuring out how to rotate the clock hands around the clock. I am using png files as the clock hands.
I am honestly unsure of how to add the clock aspect to it other than the look. Every tutorial I have found on Youtube repeats the same code and isn't quite what I need, plus its usually a year old if not older
 here's what code I have

```
       //
//  ViewController.m
//  AnalogClock
//
//  Created by edragongaming on 4/7/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 edragon. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void) countup
{
    MainInt += 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MainInt];
}

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender
{
    MainInt = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


@synthesize label;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //label.text =  @"Bye";
   [self updateTime];

}
-(void)updateTime
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    label.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate: [NSDate date] ];

    //call updateTime after 1 second
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

here's the .h code

## import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedImage;
    IBOutlet UILabel *seconds;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int MainInt;
}


-(IBAction)start:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)startAnimating;
-(void)countup;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet
UIImageView *hourHand;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *minuteHand;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *secondHand;

@end
```

Comment: Where's your code for showing the clock face image? Where's your code that attempts to show the clock hand images? The code you posted simply updates a label.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767794/analog-clock-with-uiimages-for-hands?rq=1